# Erlang gen_tcp connect question

Tags: sockets, tcp, erlang

Simple question...

This code ..

```
client() ->
    SomeHostInNet = "localhost" % to make it runnable on one machine
    {ok, Sock} = gen_tcp:connect(SomeHostInNet, 5678, 
                                 [binary, {packet, 0}]),
    ok = gen_tcp:send(Sock, "Some Data"),
    ok = gen_tcp:close(Sock).
```

is very clear except that **I don't quite understand what [binary, {packet,0}] means** ?
Any one cares to explain ?

MadSeb

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per the [gen_tcp:connect](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html#connect-4) documentation:

- `[binary, {packet, 0}]` is the list of options that's passed to the connect function.
- `binary` means that the data that is sent/received on the socket is in binary format (as opposed to, say, list format.
- `{packet, 0}`, is a little confusing and it doesn't appear to be covered in the documentation. After talking to some knowledgeable chaps in #erlang on Freenode, I found that the `packet` option specifies how many bytes indicate the packet length. Behind the scenes, the length is stripped from the packet and erlang just sends you the packet without the length. Therefore `{packet, 0}` is the same as a raw packet without a length and everything is handled but the receiver of the data. For more information on this, check out [inet:setopts](http://erldocs.com/R14B02/kernel/inet.html?i=0&search=inet:setopts#setopts/2).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

{packet,0} is used to indicate that TCP data is delivered directly to the application in an unmodified form.

binary means that received packet is delivered as a binary. (but you can still use gen_tcp:send with a message like "message")