# set parameters of gen_tcp in Elixir

Tags: tcp, erlang, elixir, erlang-otp

I'm trying to accept data through a TCP connection in Elixir using Erlang `gen_tcp`

```
{:ok, socket} = :gen_tcp.connect("127.0.0.1" ,2000,[:binary, {:packet, 0}])
receive_data(Socket, [])
```

But this isn't working due to bad arguments of `connect`. How to set binary and packet values in Elixir?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773154/erlang-gen-tcp-connect-question) It is explained about parameter meanings. But I need support to set parameters in Elixir.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at gen_tcp's documentation, you can't set a packet option on a connection. http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html#type-connect_option

Comment: Thank you!. Could you please tell me how to set connect option parameter of connect/3 method. Normally a TCP connection needs only IP and the Port. I'm little confused because I'm new to Erlang.

Comment: just `{ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:connect({127,0,0,1}, 8091, [binary, {active,true}]).` See - http://learnyousomeerlang.com/buckets-of-sockets#tcp-sockets

Comment: Thank you graymalkin. It worked. The problem was at IP. it should be
{127, 0, 0, 1}

Comment: are binary and active atoms? :binary, :active

Comment: Yes, words in erlang which start with lower case are atoms.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the parameters, which are correct, but the address.
To call into erlang, you need to use a character list

```
{:ok, socket} = :gen_tcp.connect('127.0.0.1', 2000, [:binary, packet: 0])
```

Note `'127.0.0.1'` instead of `"127.0.0.1"`.